# need some guidance on how to start a proof for $\#2^{\Omega} = 2^{\#\Omega}$

Tags: probability

$\#2^{\Omega} = 2^{\#\Omega}$

So far I know that when the size of $\Omega$ is 0, we have the $\emptyset$ and the size of the power set for $\Omega$ will be 1, or $2^{0} = 1 $

How do I start by proving this for any size $n$ of $(\Omega)$.

Also does $\Omega$ have to be finite for this to be true?

I know induction has to be used but am having trouble figuring out how to begin.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The statement is true for infinite $\Omega$ as well, given the right definition of exponentiation. for the finite case, split the subsets of $\Omega$ into those containing $x_0$ and those not containing it (after selecting an $x_0\in \Omega$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: Suppose that you know that $\{1,\dots,n\}$ has $k$ subsets. Start with one of these $k$ sets. To get a subset of $\{1,\dots,n,n+1\}$ you can either stick with the set that you have, or you can add $n+1$ to it. In this way each subset of $\{1,\dots,n\}$ gives rise to two subsets of $\{1,\dots,n+1\}$. Can you see that every subset of $\{1,\dots,n+1\}$ can be obtained in this way? So $\{1,\dots,n+1\}$ must have $2k$ subsets. Use this observation to carry out the induction step of your proof by induction.

(There are also proofs that don’t use induction, as William points out in his answer.)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $\Omega$ is a finite set of $n$ elements. So we may as well call $\Omega = \{1, 2, ..., n\}$. Every subset $X \subset \Omega$ corresponds to a binary string $\sigma_X$ of length $n$ where the $k^\text{th}$ bit of $\sigma_X$ is $0$ if $k \notin X$ and $1$ if $k \in X$. Now by a counting argument, there are $2^n$ many distinct binary strings of length $n$.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand this. So in essence we have $n$ 2-way choices, whether $k$ is in $X$ or not and so there will be $2x2x2..x2$ ($n$ times) ways the choices can be made, resulting in $2^{n}$ number of subsets.

Comment: @Lok Yes, that is the idea.